# Parse/Format ps -eo etime in minutes?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

Can someone please help me parse this output to show in total number of minutes?

Here's the command (which works as expected except for the formatting):

```
ps -eo pid,etime,command | grep some_process | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

Output (in hours, minutes, seconds)

```
03:01:24
```

I need the output to look something like:

```
181.40
```

(3 hours, 1 minute, 24 seconds displayed as a real number)

Is this possible? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ps -eo pid,etime,command | grep PID | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F : '{ printf("%.2f\n", $1*60+$2+($3/60)); }'
```

;)

**Edited:** 
An improved version (thx @alexandernst and @Nathan):

```
ps -eo pid,etimes,command | grep PID | grep -v grep | awk '{printf("%.2f\n", $2/60)}'
```

Comment: Wow, great. This works as expected. Can I just ask about the logic behind:

$1*60+$2+($3/60)

Thank you for the quick reply

Comment: $1:$2:$3 = hours:minutes:seconds. hours to minutes =  $1 * 60. seconds to minutes = $3 / 60. Got it?

Comment: This will fail if/when etime doesn't return HH:MM:SS, but just MM:SS (for example, a process that was starting in less than an hour ago)

Comment: Looks like you can use 'etimes' instead of 'etime' to get seconds directly.

Comment: The 'etimes' keyword is available on GNU ps but not on BSD ps, at least not on OSX. A more portable solution appears at: [Parse ps etime output into seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14653443/3321356)

Comment: No need of all those grep:
`ps -eo pid,etimes,command | awk '/PID/ {printf("%.2f\n", $2/60)}'`