# Can one do date math with ps output?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

if i run this command

```
ps aux | grep -ie ff1 | awk '{print $2 , $9 , $(NF-0)}'
```

i get this result:

```
7019 12:33 /var/www/html/tv1/video1.m3u8
13374 17:13 /var/www/html/tv1/asdas.m3u8
15001 05:58 /var/www/html/tv1/dfwef.m3u8
15021 05:58 /var/www/html/tv1/werwe.m3u8
15200 11:45 /var/www/html/tv1/2fsdfsf.m3u8
```

so second word in each line is  time  when process started
so is there a way i can calculate that time with

```
date +%H:%M   - awk '{print $9}'
```

so i can know how much time each proccess it was running

---

**i want a result like this:**

```
02:20 7019 12:33 /var/www/html/tv1/video1.m3u8
```

(it means proccess 7019 that starts on 12:33 has been running for 2hours and 20 minutes)

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use `ps` for this at all, but would extract the epoch time direct from procfs; subtract from the current epoch time and you have number of seconds of runtime.

Comment: ...epoch time is also rather considerably less bug prone when you get to corner cases like situations when your script is run just after midnight with processes started prior to that boundary.

Comment: maybe need something like this:   ps -o etime= -p "PID NUMBER example awk '{print $2 "

Comment: @arpak: don't use awk to parse the output. Use the `-o` flag of `ps` to request exactly the fields you want in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following commands. first one gives for the specific PID, 2nd for all processes.

```
ps -o etime= -p <PID>

ps -eo pid,etime
```

Comment: how to implement this command in mine ps aux | grep -ie ff1 | awk '{print $2 , $9 , $(NF-0)}'

Comment: Combine with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652445/parse-ps-etime-output-and-convert-it-into-seconds to convert to seconds perhaps :-)

Comment: ps aux | grep -ie ff1 | awk '{print $2 , $9 , $(NF-0)}' | ps -o etime= -p <print $2>
something like this is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should give what you want - elapsed time, PID, and start time:

```
$ ps -o etime,pid,bsdstart,cmd
    ELAPSED   PID  START CMD
      00:05 25980  18:33 bash
      00:00 26019  18:33 ps -o etime,pid,bsdstart,cmd
```

(and I second [@CharlesDuffy's sentiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173133/can-one-do-date-math-with-ps-output/45173373#comment77314564_45173133) that you definitely should *not* try to parse this output.)

Comment: how to implement in mine command ps aux | grep -ie ff1 | awk '{print $2 , $9 , $(NF-0)}'

Comment: What do you mean, @arpak?

Comment: i need to get result like this:  02:20 7019 12:33 /var/www/html/tv1/video1.m3u8
(it means proccess 7019 that starts on 12:33 has been running for 2hours and 20 minutes)

Comment: im waiting for it

Comment: look u dont understeand me  . how i can add /var/www/html/tv1/video1.m3u8 there,???? u must add something to my command so it will show all results that show now. plus time difference

Comment: Nope, I don't understand you. I don't have /var/www/html/tv1/video1.m3u8, so how am I supposed to know what you even mean? Voting to close.